# Writing SQL query for a given combination of letters

Tags: sql

I want to write a sql query wherein the fourth letter should be `'x'` and there should be `'m'` anywhere in the whole word. I am having a list of over 5000 words.

I tried the command

```
where name like '___x%m%'
```

but that would only give me those where `x` is the fourth letter and there is m after x, but how to find those names which have `x` as fourth letter and have `m` coming before `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
where name like '____x%' and name like '%m%'
```

Comment: And that will ensure all the possibilities? Even the names where there are more than a single 'm' in the name ( they might even occur before or after x) ?

Comment: @kira . . . If you want exactly one 'm', then add `and not like '%m%m%'`.

Comment: @kira . . . If you want to know when an answer was posted, you can place the mouse over the time above the name and the exact time is shown.  Often, the OP accepts the first of equivalent answers.  Of course, you might have your own reasons for accepting another answer.

Comment: Apologies Gordon, I read the comments in the other thread and was lead to believe he had posted a few seconds before you. I now know that you posted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Simply have the 2 conditions:

```
WHERE name LIKE '___x%' AND name LIKE '%m%'
```

Assuming the ___x part works for you.

Comment: its a duplicate of the another answer

Comment: There was no other answer when I posted it.

Comment: someone beat you by a minute :)

Comment: @FrancisFuerte Downvoting someone for being a few seconds slower than someone else with a similar answer is rather harsh. It's not a race.

Comment: @Yang: i did not downvote him being a few seconds slower.. dont accuse me of such a thing just because i pointed it out